# Calling Method from Native dll works first time, instacrashes on second time (due to fortran modules)?

Tags: c#, fortran, pinvoke

I'm creating a C# net4.5 console project which consumes a fortran dll. The method from this dll works fine on the first call, and instacrashes on second call, no error messages of any sort.

Running some tests, i found that ***if i don't use the module1, meaning put the variable declaration on subroutine, it works fine, on any number of calls***

**C#**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestMyArray();//WORKS FLAWLESLY
        TestMyArray();//INSTAKILLS PROGRAM
    }


    private static void TestMyArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("START");
        int size = 52;
        float[] myarray = new float[size];
        sub_(ref size, myarray);
        Console.WriteLine(myarray.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((x, y) => x + ";" + y));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    [DllImport("FortranArraySimpleTest.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern void sub_(ref int size, float[] myarray);
```

**FORTRAN**

```
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::ingammaextern
subroutine sub(size, myarray)
    use module1   ! * REMOVING MODULE USAGE FIXES THE PROBLEM
  implicit none
INTEGER  :: size
integer :: assignme
REAL, dimension(1:size) :: myarray

assignme = size
allocate(alocarray(1:assignme))

end subroutine
! ************************************begin another file***********
      MODULE module1
      IMPLICIT NONE


real, dimension(:), allocatable :: alocarray
      END MODULE module1
```

This solution, the removal of modules, is extremely cumbersome and a maintenance major headache, due to the code which made me post the question being very large.

**Environment:** GNU Fortran Compiler, windows 7 64bits, CodeBlocks for fortran, VS2012, i didn't change any compiler options.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should deallocate the array `allocarray` in the subroutine before leaving it. As it is a module variable used by host association in your routine, it will remain allocated after the subroutine is left. Trying to allocate it again when you enter the routine the second time may be the cause for your crash. Alternatively, you could check for its allocation status via the `allocated()` intrinsic function.