# Simultaneous calls of a method in a fortran dll with module variables, in C#

Tags: c#, fortran, pinvoke, gfortran

I'm trying to make calls of a Fortran method simultaneously in different threads. The executions are completely independent from each other and the main thread. The problem is that using module variables means that the variables are made global by the dll, meaning the two calls would use it, thus instacrashing the program, and so it happens. This is my interpretation, based on this [answer of Bálint Aradi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701454/calling-method-from-native-dll-works-first-time-instacrashes-on-second-time-du).

**C#**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunTwiceSync();//WORKS
        RunTwiceAsync();//INSTACRASH
    }

    private static void RunTwiceSync()
    {
        TestMyArray();
        TestMyArray();
    }

    private static void RunTwiceAsync()
    {
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            TestMyArray();
        });
        Thread t = new Thread(ts);
        t.Start();
        TestMyArray();
    }

    private static void TestMyArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("START");
        int size = 52;
        float[] myarray = new float[size];
        sub_(ref size, myarray);
        Console.WriteLine(myarray.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((x, y) => x + ";" + y));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    [DllImport("FortranArraySimpleTest.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern void sub_(ref int size, float[] myarray);
```

**FORTRAN**

```
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::ingammaextern
subroutine sub(size, myarray)
    use module1   ! * REMOVING MODULE USAGE FIXES THE PROBLEM
  implicit none
INTEGER  :: size
integer :: assignme
REAL, dimension(1:size) :: myarray

assignme = size
allocate(alocarray(1:assignme))
deallocate(alocarray)
end subroutine
! ************************************begin another file***********
      MODULE module1
      IMPLICIT NONE


real, dimension(:), allocatable :: alocarray
      END MODULE module1
```

This solution, the removal of modules, is extremely cumbersome and a maintenance major headache, due to the code which made me post the question being very large.

**Environment:** GNU Fortran Compiler, windows 7 64bits, CodeBlocks for fortran, VS2012, i didn't change any compiler options.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time

Comment: It is not evident from your code why the array should be in the module in the first place nor why it is supposed to be a maintenance problem to make it local. You do not have to remove all modules.

Comment: This is a sample code to illustrate the problem. The original version of the code has more than 50 module variables, located in two modules. Those variables are used in multiple functions in multiple files. Imagine how fun it would be to add even a share of these 50 parameters in the parameter lists of several functions. Now imagine if you need to add or remove a parameter.

Comment: This the art of program design, share what needs to be shared, keep nonshared state in a derived type instead of a module what cannot be shared. Almost every module can be changed for a class with type-bound procedures in a straightforward way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can be done is to change the module for a derived type, which is then passed with every call

```
module orig
  use whatever

  interfaces

  small types

  variables

contains

  procedures

end module
```

to

```
module state_class

  use whatever

  interfaces

  small types

  shared variables

  type state
    non shared variables
  contains
    procedure :: the procedures
    (not obligatory)
  end type

contains

  procedures changed to accept one additional argument:
  a passed dummy argument class(state)
  or just a regular dummy argument type(state)

end module
```

Every thread has own `state` class instance and passes it explicitly or as a passed dummy argument.

Comment: Sounds promising, will try this.